# Unable to call "findObjectsInBackground" in parse in swift

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform

In my following code when i am calling **openDatabase()** it is showing **fatal error** as **pathToDatabase** is nil.
Actually when i am calling **findObjectsInBackground** i am unable to enter the block. so that i am getting **pathToDatabase** as nil ? Please help me.

```
import UIKit  
import Parse  

class existDatabase: NSObject {

    var databaseFileName = ""
    var pathToDatabase: String!
    var database: FMDatabase!
    var userAccessCode = ""


    override init()
    {
        super.init()


        if let accesscode = USERDEFAULTS.string(forKey: "UserAccessCode"){

            let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "AccessCode")
            query.whereKey("RegisterCode", equalTo: accesscode)
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, err) in
                if err == nil{
                    if let users = objects{
                        if users.isEmpty {

                        }
                        else{

                            for post in users{
                                if let surgery = post["SurgeryType"] as? String{

                                    if surgery == "Trigger Finger"{
                                        self.databaseFileName = "thumbtriggerfinger"
                                        self.pathToDatabase = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thumbtriggerfinger", ofType: "db")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print(err?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func openDatabase() -> Bool {
        if database == nil {

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToDatabase) {
                database = FMDatabase(path: pathToDatabase)
            }
        }

        if database != nil {
            if database.open() {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have code something like

```
 let x = existDatabase()
 x.openDatabase()
```

The problem is that you have an asynchronous block in your initialiser, which means that the object won't be fully initialised when the initialiser returns; the Parse background fetch is not yet complete.

You get a crash because the implicitly unwrapped optional is `nil`.  The fact that you needed to use an implicitly unwrapped optional is your first warning sign.  You should be able to use non-optionals for a property set in an initialiser, but you can't because the properties are set in the closure.

Having an asynchronous operation in an initialiser is rarely a good design.

I would suggest you restructure your code so that `openDatabase` performs the asynchronous operation and accepts a completion hander.

Also, stylistically, class names should start with a capital letter, and are typically nouns, not verbs.

```
class DatabaseManager {

    static database(for accessCode: String, completion: @escaping (FMDatabase?,Error?)) {
        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "AccessCode")
        query.whereKey("RegisterCode", equalTo: accessCode)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, err) in
            if err == nil{
                if let users = objects, !users.isEmpty {
                    for post in users{
                        if let surgery = post["SurgeryType"] as? String{
                            if surgery == "Trigger Finger"{
                                let pathToDatabase = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thumbtriggerfinger", ofType: "db")
                                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathToDatabase) {
                                    database = FMDatabase(path: pathToDatabase)
                                    if database.open() {
                                        completion(database,nil)
                                    } else {
                                        completion(nil, nil)
                                    }
                                break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(nil,nil)
                }
            }
            else{
                completion(nil, err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it using:

```
if let accesscode = USERDEFAULTS.string(forKey: "UserAccessCode"){
    DatabaseManager.database(for: accesscode) { (database, error) in {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error: (error!.localalizedDescription)")
            return
        } 
        guard let db = database else {
            print("No database")
            return
        }
        // Do something with db
    }
}
```